# Pass search query to google maps JS api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a way to pass search query to google maps JS API. So for, all I could see is incorporating search box into google maps. I'm developing an application in which user does not have to type into google. For example, there would be a botton in my landing page saying "schools in Boston". Just a click of it could highlight the schools in Boston.
Something like this [Schools in Boston](https://www.google.com/maps/search/schools+in+boston/@42.3362406,-71.1030957,15z/data=!3m1!4b1)

I could not find a way to get the same functionality without the user typing into a search box.
I'm expecting a API call like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&q=schools+in+boston but could not find any. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Here's the api documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests  and the code they provide:

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

Answer (score 5):

Here's the api documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests  and the code they provide:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```